# Need to capture F12 key and Shift F12 key combination IE8

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

In the silverlight application if I set Windowless to true on the plugin then <kbd>F12</kbd> key is not captured on KeyUp for the layout root.

I am trying to do this application wide.  So I need to capture <kbd>F12</kbd> and <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> <kbd>F12</kbd> no matter where the user types it.

Currently I am trying to capture it on the Keyup event of the top level layout root.

This works for IE7, but not IE8

This works for <kbd>F12</kbd> with IE8 `windowless = false`

This does not work for <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> <kbd>F12</kbd> for IE8 `windowless=false`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be a design limitation imposed by Microsoft similar to how you can't capure <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>DEL</kbd>`.

<kbd>F12</kbd> a shortcut to open the Developer Tools window in IE8. So IE8 probably consumes those key-presses.

Answer (score 0):

The difference in behaviour between window and windowless is that for a windowed (`windowless=false`) control Windows can send the key message firstly to the that window before any parents (IE in this case) can handle it. So Silverlight can manage it and cancel it before IE has it, whereas with windowless IE is dispatching the key event to the control so can deal with it.

I'm not sure how you can swallow the keypress in Silverlight but in JavaScript you can cancel it using `event.returnValue`, `e.preventDefault()` or `return false` depending which browser you need to support. The below snippet cancels most key presses in IE9 including F12.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){           
        window.event.returnValue=false; 
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
});
```